# springbootのWEBアプリをDocker上でデバッグしたい（VS CodeのRemote Development）

Tags: docker, vscode, spring-boot

VSCodeを使って、SpringbootのWEBアプリを作成しました。
https://tech-lab.sios.jp/archives/19941

VSCodeのデバッグと実行で、
HelloController.javaでブレイクポイントがはれることを確認できたので
jarファイルを作成し、Window上でDockerで動くことを確認しました。

次にDocker上の環境をデバッグできないものかと、調べていると
VSCodeの拡張機能であるRemote Developmentを使えばよさそうでしたので、以下を参考に
devcontainer.jsonとDockerファイルを作成しました。
https://speakerdeck.com/noriyukitakei/visual-studio-code-plus-docker-plus-remote-developmentdetomcatshang-falsewebapuriwochao-jian-dan-nidebatugu?slide=38

VSCodeのRemote Development拡張機能をインストールしたので
VSCode左下に現れた「＞＜」のようなボタンを押下し、
Reopen in Containerを選択したのですが、VSCodeが再起動したのち以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
an error occurred building the image
```

以下のファイルで足りていない設定や、誤りなどありますでしょうか？
プロジェクトフォルダ.devcontainer
devcontainer.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
 
  "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
 
  "forwardPorts": [8080],
 
  # コンテナに入ったときに最初にここで指定したものがカレントディレクトリになります。
  "workspaceFolder": "/opt/project",
 
  # ホストOSのVisual Studio Codeのプロジェクト直下のディレクトリをコンテナの/opt/projectディレクトリにマウント>します。
  "mounts": [
    "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/opt/project,type=bind,consistency=cached"
  ]
 
  # コンテナが生成されたときに、コンテナ側にインストールする拡張機能です。
  # これを指定しないと、コンテナが再生成すると拡張機能が消えます。
  # 今回はJava Extension PackとTomcat for Javaをインストールします。
  "extensions": [
    "adashen.vscode-tomcat",
    "vscjava.vscode-java-pack"
  ]
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:14.0.1

#COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo-0.0.1.jar

#ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/demo-0.0.1.jar"]
# ローカルのソースコードをマウントするためのディレクトリを作成します。 RUN mkdir /opt/project

# Mavenをインストールします。 RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install maven
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問文中からリンクされているスライドの説明は、少し古く、かつ Tomcat のものなので今回行おうとしていることの参考として適していないように思われます。

- [Developing inside a Container using Visual Studio Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

をベースにして、 Spring Boot 向け機能拡張を追加インストールすれば良さそうです。

---

Spring Boot の Maven プロジェクト作成済み、 Docker Desktop for Windows セットアップ済みとします。

1. 機能拡張 [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) をローカルの VSCode にインストールします(補足: [質問文中のスライド](https://speakerdeck.com/noriyukitakei/visual-studio-code-plus-docker-plus-remote-developmentdetomcatshang-falsewebapuriwochao-jian-dan-nidebatugu?slide=32)に従って機能拡張 [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) をインストール済みであれば、Remote - Containers も導入されているはずです)。
2. コマンドパレット(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)で "**Remote-Containers: Add Development Container Configuration Files...**" を選択します。ウィザードを進め、構築する環境を設定します。例えば Java 11 の Maven 環境であれば:

   - "Java > 11 > None(Node をインストールしない) > Install Maven にチェック > (何もチェックしない) "
3. ウィザードを完了させると、 `.devcontainer` ディレクトリに 2 ファイル `devcontainer.json`, `Dockerfile` が作成されます。 `devcontainer.json` を編集し、 機能拡張 [Spring Boot Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Pivotal.vscode-boot-dev-pack) をインストールするように次の通り `Pivotal.vscode-boot-dev-pack` を追加します:

   - ```
       "extensions": [
         "vscjava.vscode-java-pack",
         "Pivotal.vscode-boot-dev-pack"
       ],
     ```
4. コマンドパレットで "**Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container...**" を選択します。 Docker イメージが構築され、コンテナが起動します。

---

(コメントを受けて追記)

上記の手順で作成した環境は、ホスト(Windows)のディレクトリをコンテナ側でマウントし、双方で共有した状態になっています。

本文冒頭に記載したリンク先では、共有方式以外についても説明があります。

> While using this approach to [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) the local filesystem into a container is convenient, it does have some performance overhead on Windows and macOS. There are [some techniques](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance) that you can apply to improve disk performance, or **you can [open a repository in a container using a isolated container volume](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-open-a-git-repository-or-github-pr-in-an-isolated-container-volume) instead**.

Comment: .devcontainerは自動で作成されるのですね。早速.devcontainerを一度削除し、頂いた手順を実行しましたところ、デバッグできることを確認できました。

Comment: ひとつ、イメージがつかないのですが、Remote-Containersを使うことで、Dockerコンテナ上のデバッグを行うかと思いますが、
Windows上のソースはコンテナ上に配置（マウント？）しなくていいものなのでしょうか？
見当違いにもdevcontainer.json等を作成しようとしていたのですが、devcontainer.jsonなどのworkspaceFolderなどで、
コンテナ上にコードが展開→ビルドしたものが動かされるのではと考えていたもので、どのようにしてjavaが動いているのだろうと思った次第です（すいません、質問が変かもしれないです）

Comment: "Open Folder in Container" で指定したフォルダがコンテナにマウントされ、ホスト(Windows)とコンテナで共有状態になっています。このためどちら側からでも編集できます。これは[`docker inspect` コマンド](https://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/commandline/inspect.html) 結果の `Mounts` セクションを見ることで確認できます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。とても勉強になりました。